# Não finalizar instancia durante processamento

Tags: php, amazon-aws, elastic-beanstalk

tenho um processamento que ocorre em minhas estancias, porém, algumas vezes o "auto scaling" finaliza a instancia no meio do processo (que pode demorar).
Já procurei na documentação uma forma de bloquear isso no inicio do processamento e depois desbloquear, sem sucesso.
O processo ocorre utilizando o PHP-CLI.

Alguém sabe alguma biblioteca ou método que me permita fazer isso?

Comment: Tem como você [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar o código utilizado?

Comment: Ainda não tenho o código que faça isso, imagino que seja da biblioteca AWS

Comment: Você precisa de ajuda em um código, mas não tem código? Não entendi.

Comment: Acredito que "instance protection" é o que voce busca: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-protection-for-auto-scaling/

Comment: Exatamente @Julio_AWS_DevRel ! Obrigado!